# PowerBI: Display top 5 quarters except first one

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I want to display top 5 quarters except the current one. Say top 6 quarters are FY19Q1, FY19Q2, FY19Q3, FY19Q4, FY20Q1, FY20Q2 and current quarter is FY20Q2.

So I want to display line chart for FY19Q1, FY19Q2, FY19Q3, FY19Q4, FY20Q1. That is except the current quarter FY20Q2. Could anyone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: share you data and show us what did you tried till now, adding more info like dataset, design and so on will help you get answers quickly.

Comment: Sorry since the data is sensitive I can't share it here. I checked top N and advanced filtering which didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your Quarters in the x-Axis and your value (for example: Sales) in a bar chart.

Then simply drag and drop your Quarters into the filter pane of the bar chart and exclude the current quarter.

**Update**

If you want it variable then add a custom column (Name:`CurrQuarterBool`) in your query designer with the following formula:

```
= Date.IsInCurrentQuarter([YourDateColumn])
```

Now just drag and drop the `CurrQuarterBool` Column in your filter of the visual.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes but for next quarter it should automatically update. The method you mentioned above won't update automatically. Every quarter I should manually update after refresh.